# Simulating eMMC memory for development before actual PCB is ready

Tags: linux, ioctl, flash-memory

We're working on a product that contains an embedded Linux system. The storage will be an eMMC device. I would like to possibly take advantage of some of the features of an eMMC device, like the boot partitions, possibly the RPMB partition, and multiple user partitions.

However, our board won't be ready for quite some time, and I would like to get a jump on learning how to work with an eMMC device as soon as possible - including using ioctl (or whatever is available) to work with it at a low level.

Are there other devices that work so similarly to an eMMC as to be a good stand in? From my reading of the JEDEC standard, it seems like eMMC is very closely related to SD cards. Do SD cards have the device-level partitioning and such as eMMC?

Answer (score 1):

No, SD cards didn't have those device-level partitions, such as boot partitions, RPMB partitons, and GPP partitions.